# Can you add a texture to an XNA project with code?

Tags: c#, xna, runtime, textures, loading

I've been trying to develop games recently, so I've just started learning XNA today, after finally throwing in the towel on a WinForms game. So, I know that you are SUPPOSED to load textures in using the Visual Studio solution explorer, but is there any way to do that with a line of code, something akin to `Game.LoadTexture(string filename);` or something like that? Because I prefer to do everything from the code to keep it all straight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using XNA 3.1 or earlier, you could look at `Texture.FromFile` ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture.fromfile%28v=XNAGameStudio.31%29.aspx)). This method works with `1D`, `2D`, and `3D` textures, and should be used in the `LoadContent` method.

However, if you are using XNA 4.0, there is no `Texture.FromFile` method. Instead, there's `Texture.FromStream` (I don't think there's a `FromStream` method for a `Texture3D` or `Texture` though). You could create a method to load a texture (in this case, a `Texture2D`) from a file: (code from [here](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/56474/344272.aspx))

```
private Texture2D TextureFromFile(string path)  
{  
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);  
    Texture2D t2d = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, fs);  
    fs.Close();  
    return t2d;  
}
```

Also see [here](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/68816/431977.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495156/how-do-i-load-a-texture-in-xna-at-runtime) for more info, especially the latter for getting a `texture` or `Texture3D` from a file.
HTH